# why particular note guids return no content?

Tags: evernote

While using the API to fetch notes from a notebook, some specific notes always return no content, whereas others respond normally. These same notes are accessible from either Evernote's web client or the platform-specific (i.e. Windows and Mac) clients.

Under what circumstances may this happen?

Comment: Can you add some more detail, like what SDK you are using, and perhaps be clear about whether you are able to create a trivial note and get its content? When you say "no content" please clarify what that means.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late response, I failed to notice your comment. I'm on a browser, using the thrift-based client. I am trying to download a few hundred notes, one by one, so as not to flood the server. The problem is that some specific notes always seem to timeout for some reason.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. We do have some sort of a rate limit in place, so maybe you're hitting that? If you're catching an exception, maybe try logging the error code and parameter? (Also, hi Ben! Long time)

Comment: Thanks for your time. The situation is like this: initially, I use noteStore.findNotesMetadata to get a list of note guids. Then I enter a loop to get one by one the node contents using noteStore.getNote. For some note guids I get back the expected response, while for others I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined". I don't see any obvious difference between the notes that respond and those that raise an exception. All notes are perfectly accessible from the Evernote web client.

Comment: I also get simple timeouts - I have set a limit at 6 secs which should be more than enough since the server usually responds in a couple of secs.

Comment: @akhaku (Hi Ammar!)

Comment: Don't have too many ideas... Sounds like you're using the javascript SDK. Can you get a stack trace or line number? If you're fetching a note `withResourcesData` and the note has a lot of resources it may be hitting your 6 second timeout?

Comment: Here is the error I get: {
  "errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/task/index.js:56:18",
    "IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/thrift-node-binary.js:138:11)",
    "emitNone (events.js:72:20)",
    "IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)",
    "endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)",
    "nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)",
    "process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:392:17)"
  ]
}